# Get destination of silverlight link

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink

I visited a web page with an embedded silverlight.
If I press a specific button on that page, I will get a download window in Firefox. So I think this is just a link. Can you tell me how I can get the HTTP address of the link?
I want to create an http link to the same destination but for this, I need the destination..

Best,
dwi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Just download in Firefox and go to download history.
There you can right click and select "Copy download link".